# Merging Linestrings to bigger Linestrings

Tags: python, shapefile, graph

I have a shapefile with the Linestring elements which looks like this:
[image]

Here you see a lot of small lines (about 582 in total). Is there a way to extract pure end-to-end lines? For now, I tried to combine Linestring elements together as the first step by the following code:

```
def connect_lineparts(geom_list):
    def dfs(adj_list, visited, vertex, result, key):
        visited.add(vertex)
        result[key].append(vertex)
        for neighbor in adj_list[vertex]:
            if neighbor not in visited:
                dfs(adj_list, visited, neighbor, result, key)

    adj_list = defaultdict(list)
    for x, y in geom_list:
        adj_list[x].append(y)
        adj_list[y].append(x)

    result = defaultdict(list)
    visited = set()
    for vertex in adj_list:
        if vertex not in visited:
            dfs(adj_list, visited, vertex, result, vertex)
    return result
```

When I combine the result points together into Linestring I have something like this:

[image]

You can see there are some lines which were created by very distant points and absent of some small lines which were presented initially.

Answer (score 1):

For doing this kind of thing in Python I would recommend looking into the [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project.html) library, where the [`linemerge`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.linemerge) command will combine chains of contiguous `LineString`s into larger `LineString`s.

If you want to extract 'pure end-to-end lines' you could use the [`unary_union`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union) command to merge all your lines into one `MultiLineString`, which will then consist of all the (merged) 'pure' lines.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but the following script returns me 545 lines. That is too much:

`shapes = gpd.read_file(path).geometry.values
merged = linemerge(shapes)`

Comment: @МаринаЛисниченко In what sense is it 'too much'? linemerge does not split up lines that cross, it only merges lines where the start of one coincides with the end of another. I expanded my answer with how you can split intersecting lines